# strcpy() generates segmentation fault on variable sized array of strings

Tags: c

I'm learning "C" language, I have created a program as below that would copy command-line arguments to another variable sized array (of strings) and print that array starting from index 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_array(const char* arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

void copy_array(char* dest[], const char* src[]) {
    for (int i = 0; src[i]; i++) {
        strcpy(dest[i], src[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;
    char args[argc][256];
    copy_array(args, argv);
    print_array(&args[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I call it via './a.out one two three four five', it throws a segmentation fault. Using gdc, I could see that `strcpy()` did this. I'm just learning it, can't really find the cause. Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using fixed length buffers is how you have ugly buffer-overflow bugs. Why not `strdup`?

Comment: Looks like a home-work assignment.

Comment: Jaymin Suthar, What compiler are you using that did not warn about line `copy_array(args, argv);`?

Comment: I'm using gcc 8.2.0 on an Ubuntu machine, I'm sorry for not mentioning it before, the compiler did warn me about it.

Comment: Your parameters are wrong, copy_array should take char* or char dest[], a char*[] is the same as char**, not correct for strcpy, 'argv' is an array of strings, you need to pass one of them, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that an array of arrays of `char` is not the same as an array of pointers to `char`.  That may seem pedantic, but underlying structure is different.

In fact, your compiler should be issuing a warning (if it's not, you should increase your warning levels).

More specifically, if `a` is an array of array of chars, then `a[i]` is an address relative to the start of your array that can only be calculated because the compiler knows how large each sub array is (e.g. `256` in your case).

Whereas, if `a` is an array of pointers to `char`, no calculation is required, `a[i]` contains the value of the pointer itself.

By passing an array of arrays where an array of pointers is expected, you are causing the compiler to calculate the address incorrectly (i.e. undefined behavior) and hence your segfault.

If you want to be consistent and use an array of pointers everywhere, your code might look more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_array(char* arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

void copy_array(char* dest[], char* src[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; src[i]; i++) {
      dest[i] = malloc(strlen(src[i]) + 1);
      strcpy(dest[i], src[i]);
    }
    dest[i] = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;
    char *args[argc + 1];
    copy_array(args, argv);
    print_array(&args[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it worked. And now I understand arrays vs pointers better, too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the copy_array loop execute after the actual length of the array

```
void copy_array(char* dest[], const char* src[]) {
    for (int i = 0; src[i]; i++) {
        strcpy(dest[i], src[i]);
    }
}
```

should be changed to

```
void copy_array(char* dest[], const char* src[], int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        strcpy(dest[i], src[i]);
    }
}
```

Also print array should be changed to:

```
void print_array(const char* arr[], int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `argv[argc]` will always be NULL

Comment: @FatalError, I cannot understand what you are trying to point to in my answer